# Kernel Load Screen Flickering

Tags: gnome, hard-drive, gnome-terminal, ubuntu-gnome

I am a fairly new Ubuntu user and I request you to bear with me.

Problem:-
I recently ran a `sudo do-release-upgrade` on my system. The result was a warning stating low-disk space 0 bytes remaining. So, I had to terminate this process in the middle. After shutting down and starting again, the kernel Load Screen is flickering and eventually, the whole process hangs.

The last message on the screen after hang is:

```
[drm:intel_pipe_config_compare [i915]] *ERROR* mismatch in ips_enabled (expected 1,found 0)
```

Comment: It is difficult to impossible to fix broken upgrades as interrupting the system leaves it in an unstable state. First make space on your hard drive , from a live CD / USB if necessary. Then check your repos and I would chroot into the system and run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` see if that fixes the problem . If no we need a lot of information and error messages. More likely then not you are better off with a fresh install and restoring your data from back up.

Comment: Okay,please guide me further:- How can I login to the system and get a backup of my root folder or home folder or both? @bodhi.zazen

Comment: Boot a live USB , mount the hard drive, and copy the contents to a second USB or hard drive.

Comment: and after a fresh install, How can I replace the data or how can I set it up from the backup?

Comment: Mount the USB / Hard drive where you copied the data and copy it back.

Comment: Can I make a live usb with the latest version for this purpose? I.e. using latest Ubuntu version

Comment: @bodhi.zazen just to be double sure, the procedure is to backup-data, remove ubuntu and grub, make a fresh install and then replace the data, right Sir?

Comment: Sure that is what I would do

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @bodhi.zazen, installing ubuntu from the scratch fixed everything. Make a backup your home folder and root folder and  you are good to go to perform a new install.